# How can I find the full path name for the icons for running apps shown at the bottom of the Ubuntu MATE screen?

Tags: icons, mate

I have a 3rd party program I installed on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. It is not a debian package, so I had to download and install it myself.

I added it to the MATE Menu but the menu editor used the default launcher icon. When the program runs, the app's icon shows up at the bottom of the screen with the rest of the open windows.

Is it possible to find the full pathname for the icon so I can us it in the menu?

Comment: The question lacks any meaningful information. What software? Installed how? And how are you sure it has an icon?

Comment: What is the name of "3rd party program"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look the folder with your application and find possible icon file here.
Then run MATE Menu Editor (`mozo`) again and choose found icon for you application.
Other way to call MATE Menu Editor is to click on *Applications* and select *Edit Menus*:

[image: Edit Menus]

go to the category of your application, then edit its icon by left click on it or right-click and selecting *Properties*.

You can make the same for the launcher on desktop by right-clicking on it and selecting *Properties*:

[image: Properties]

then click on big icon button:

[image: edit Properties]

and choose needed icon file

[image: selected icon]

and enjoy.

Notes:
1. MATE Menu Editor may be installed with `sudo apt install mozo`.
2. Some applications does not have icons for taskbar / dock and will show with default one ([image: mate-panel-launcher.png]).